# RSS feedparser to MySQL database not populating

Tags: python, mysql, feedparser

I am using Feedparser in Python to collect a RSS feed and then using mysql.connector to enter the data into my database. I have been trying lots of different variations, but I have hit a bit of a block.

Feedparser is collecting the data fine, I can output to file or display, but when I try and enter it into the MySQL database it doesn't work, but also doesn't throw any error messages. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please see the latest iteration of my code below.

```
       import feedparser
       import mysql.connector

       RSS_in = feedparser.parse("https://examplewebsite.com/feed/") # RSS feed location

       for item in RSS_in['items']:

           title = item.title

           description = item.description

           content = item.content

           print(title)

           print(description)

           print(content)


        def save_feed(items):

            sql = "INSERT INTO RSS_news VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

            con = mysql.connector.connect(user='username', password='password',  host='localhost',    database='databse_one') # Connection details for database

            with con:

                cur = con.cursor()

                for item in items:

                        cur.execute(format(sql % (item.title, item.description, item.content)))

            print('successful')

            con.commit()

            cur.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [MySQL Insert Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

If number of columns in table is more than the number of data attributes we've to save, mentioned those fields in `insert statement`.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO RSS_news (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
```

Replace `col1, col2, col3` with actual database table fields names.

**Multiple Insert**: [Python MySQL - Insert Data in table](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-insert/) - To insert multiple in a single go, you can use `executemany`.

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.executemany(sql, items)
```